# There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address

Tags: azure, service-reference

I have created a solution in Azure which consumes a WCF service. My problem is that I can't add a service reference. It gives me the error:

> There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: @Wingu you got any soln?

Comment: @Shankar, my problem resulted from renaming the wcf. This all I did to get it working again.                                             (FileName GenericService.Svc)                                                 original; "<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="GenericService.Service1" CodeBehind="ServiceGeneric.svc.vb" %>"

I changed it to; "<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="GenericService.ServiceGeneric" CodeBehind="ServiceGeneric.svc.vb" %>"

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but for the sake of people from the furture, here's what we've figured out so far ...

If you want to find the exact error being thrown, you can set includeExceptionDetailInFaults to true.

In your service's web.config:

```
<!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

Note: this will not solve the problem, but will let you know exactly what is causing it.

Another note: I stole the opening line from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/979/).